# Qual á melhor versão Xampp / PHP , para atualizar e qual a diferença?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Estou querendo atualizar meu XAMPP Version: 1.8.3, mais o PHP Version 5.5.15, porém estou com umas dúvidas:

- Qual é a melhor versão para atualizar, se é a (5.5.38, 5.6.24 & 7.0.9)?
- Se isto irá afetar nos meus códigos ou não?
- Se tem alguma diferença entre essas versões ?

Comment: Em resumo, o ciclo de vida do PHP está aqui: http://php.net/supported-versions.php - O mínimo a se usar são as versões com _security fix_, o resto é detalhe.

Comment: poque, é um sistema de uso frequente, e to analisando melhor para que não acabe afetando, causando problema, perca de tempo, para solucionar. E com isso, irei fazer um backup e testar primeiro na maquina de teste antes . mais agradeço a ajudar de todos. :D

Comment: Entre 5.5.x e 5.6.x não terá mudanças significativas que causem transtornos. Talvez alguns regex ou um retorno de função dê pau, mas aí vai ajeitando sem muita dificuldade. Se quer ter menos trabalho, não pule direto para o 7.x. Mas recomendo que tente migrar para essa versão mais atual php7 para não ficar parado no tempo. O mercado te atropela se você parar no caminho.

Answer (score 7):

São duas coisas a se considerar:

## Segurança

É fundamental que se use no mínimo as versões do PHP que tenham `security fix`, ou seja, que mesmo não recebendo novas atualizações, tenham vulnerabilidades corrigidas.

Para saber o ciclo de vida do PHP, há um link oficial com um gráfico razoavelmente claro, no link a seguir:

> http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Usando as versões que ainda estão no gráfico para a data atual, está tudo OK. Sabendo o final do ciclo de vida do produto ajuda você a se organizar para se atualizar a tempo de não correr riscos.

## Recursos

A cada nova versão, mudam-se os recursos disponíveis, novas funcionalidades são acrescentadas, funcionalidades existentes são melhoradas (nem sempre, mas é o que se espera), e normalmente há melhorias internas de funcionalidade, aumentando a velocidade e estabilidade da linguagem (dentro do que a base do PHP permite).

Algumas funções são removidas, ou marcadas para remoção (indicadas na documentação como *deprecated*, muitas vezes traduzida errada para "depreciada", que não é a mesma coisa).

Isto por si só não é razão para atualização, se você não precisa de fato destas melhorias. Muitas vezes o risco de quebrar alguma aplicação existente não justifica a pressa na troca de versões.

Para mudança de versão, o recomendável é consultar o *changelog* e notas de atualização com carinho, e avaliar onde isto vai afetar suas aplicações.

As orientações mais detalhadas para mudança de versão se encontram aqui:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/appendices.php

Seguindo estes guias, você pode se antecipar e atualizar as aplicações para uma mudança mais tranquila, e em seguida fazer o *upgrade*.

#### Outros componentes do XAMPP

Me ative ao PHP por ser o elemento mais complexo do conjunto, mas o mesmo raciocínio se aplica ao Apache MySQL/MariaDB e qualquer outro componente.

Eu recomendaria, inclusive, **não** usar XAMPP nestes casos, e sim instalar separadamente cada um dos componentes, pois o ciclo de vida de cada um é completamente diferente. O XAMPP é excelente para uma instalação rápida numa máquina de desenvolvimento e testes.

Para uso num ambiente de produção, já começa a me lembrar aquelas TVs antigas que vinham com um aparelho VHS embutido. Pode ser prático na hora de instalar, mas se precisar mudar/consertar qualquer coisa, dá mais trabalho.

Answer (score 4):

Vai de acordo com sua necessidade. No momento estou usando a versão **5x** que se encontra estável.

Há apenas algumas coisas que você deve-se ater.

Por exemplo, na versão **7x** do php, algumas funções foram removidas.

No documentação tem esse exemplo abaixo

```
class foo {
  function foo() {
    echo 'Eu sou um construtor';
  }
}
```

Na versão 7x ele irá gerar o seguinte erro

```
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be      constructors in a future version of PHP; foo has a deprecated constructor in example.php on line 3
```

Temos ainda a função `ldap_sort()` que foi descontinuada e `mysql_*()` que foram removidas. Claro, que há várias mudanças da versão 5x para 7x, porém dependendo da sua aplicação, pode ser que não seja afetado nada.

## Atualização

As versões anteriores a 5.6 foram descontinuadas. Veja mais nesse [link](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: 5x não é estável. 5.6 é estável 5.5 é old e qualquer coisa antes disso foi descontinuado. O ideal é usar sempre a versão mais nova mas sabemos que a realidade das hospedagens brasileiras impedem isso de acontecer.

Comment: Você está se precipitando ao falar "qualquer coisa antes disso (5.5) foi descontinuado. Não podemos passar esse tipo de coisa pro pessoal que está iniciando.

Comment: Qualquer versão antes do 5.5 está descontinuada. Isso é fato inegável. Não há precipitação nenhuma no meu comentário. Recomendar versões abaixo da 5.6 em produção é o tipo de coisa que faz o pessoal que está iniciando passar o dobro de trabalho para aprender uma linguagem simples como PHP.